# Accessing iPhone/iPod video gallery

Tags: iphone, sdk, video

how I can access the video galley in my iPhone view SDK.
What the object I must to use to this that task.

I want to show all videos ( on iPhone/iPod ) in my app and then upload selected videos on web server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

On your class, you will need to implement the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069-CH3-SW8) protocol and wire it up to the `delegate` property on the picker.  You should be able to get the location of the media selected from `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` once the user has selected something.

```
// untested
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // this is the file system url of the media
    NSURL* videoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    // TODO: read in data at videoUrl and write upload it to your server
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is `UIImagePickerController` to choose a video, and `MPMoviePlayerController` and `MPMoviePlayerViewController` for playback.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `UIImagePickerController`, be sure to play around with the `sourceType` property to access the library instead of the live camera.  See `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType` for details.

These are your options:

```
enum {
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary,
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
NSArray *mediaTypesAllowed = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.image", @"public.movie", nil];
[imagePickerController setMediaTypes:mediaTypesAllowed];
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```